# PhotoImage no such file or directory error

Tags: python, tkinter

So basically, I am trying to learn tkinter but the PhotoImage gadget won't work.

My code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
logo = tk.PhotoImage(file ="monky.gif")

def test():
    print("Hello World")

text = tk.Label(root, text = "Hello World")
text.pack()
```

I also tried this:

```
logo = tk.PhotoImage(file ="/Users/MinecraftMaster/Desktop/Python/Tests/monky.gif")
```

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MinecraftMaster/Desktop/Python/Tests/Tkinter Test.py", line 4, in <module>
    logo = tk.PhotoImage(file ="monky.gif")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3539, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3495, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "monky.gif": no such file or directory
```

This is a picture of my directory:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFTCD.jpg

Edit: A friend helped me solve this issue. For anyone else with this issue, just put the directory in a variable and then call it. Thanks to everyone who tried to help

Comment: Your screenshot show the image as being in a folder called `Tkinter Test`.  Your code is trying to load it from a folder called `Tests`.  Of course that fails...

Comment: Thanks for trying but it still doesn't solve the problem. What I'm thinking is that Mac doesn't support this way of refrencing a directory, don't know tho...

Comment: The mac supports it just fine. The fact is, the file `monky.gif` simply doesn't exist in the current working directory. Either the directory is wrong, or you meant to spell it `monkey.gif` (or some other name). What happens when you type the command `ls monky.gif` at the same prompt where you're trying to run the script?

Comment: @BryanOakley OP has provided image which clearly shows that the file name is correct and it exists.

Comment: @BlackThunder: the OP has shown that the file exists _somewhere_, but hasn't shown that it's in the current working directory.

Comment: @BryanOakley The console highlights "monky" in red and says "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: The code you posted does not have a syntax error. And if you have a syntax error, you won't get the error `couldn't open "monky.gif"...`. since the syntax error would prevent you from getting to that line.

Comment: @BryanOakley I’m talking about “ls monkey.gif”

Answer (score 1):

@Omaro_IB. Below image shows the script I used and the result.
[image: monky]

You need to ensure `monky.gif` file is in the same directory as your python script file, e.g. `monky.py`.

For the image to appear, you need the `image=logo` and `compound='top'` options in the `tk.Label` method to tell tkinter to display the image and text together such the the image is at the top.

Hope the above helps.

**Update: How to check `monky.gif` file is in the same directory as your python script file.**

Open a terminal e.g. press `Ctr`+`Alt`+`T`. If your image and python files  are in your Home_folder/Desktop/test_folders, then type the `cd` command in the terminal to get to your folder (i.e. directory). Then use the `ls` command to list out your files in that folder. These commands is to help you see that your python file (e.g. `monky.py`) and `monky.gif` files are in the same directory. If these files aren't in the same folder than the image will not appear.

```
$ cd Desktop/test_folder/
$ ls
monky.gif  monky.py
```

Comment: In linux, the command `ls` will list the items in the directory in which the command is issued. The other command you need to know is `cd` for change directory. To issue these commands, you need to open a linux terminal. In Ubuntu, you can press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`call up the terminal. See update above.

Comment: _"In linux, do a ls command to make sure your monky.gif file is in the same directory as your python script file."_ is an incorrect statement. The file needs to be in the current working directory. That could be different from the location of the script.

Comment: @SunBear: your answer is still wrong. Relative paths (ie: filenames that don't start with "/") are relative to the current working directory, not relative to the script that is using the relative path.

Comment: @BryanOakley My script/answer does not use "/" but "./" which is relative to the present directory.

Comment: @SunBear: right, _relative_ to the _present_ directory. That may be different than the directory that the script is in. Again, relative paths are relative to the current working directory, but your answer says it's relative to the directory with the script. The directory with the script may or may not be the current working directory.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't placed a widget which contains the photo like a label and then it should appear.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
photo = tk.PhotoImage(file = "monkey.gif")
label = tk.Label(image = photo).pack()
def test():
    print("Hello World")

text = tk.Label(root, text = "Hello World")
text.pack()
```

What the window looks like 
https://gyazo.com/8ce068a49c99a8a7f53f64cd5024a48f

Comment: the problem is not with the widget/syntax, but because the computer cannot find the actual file. If you look at the error it says: couldn't open "monky.gif": no such file or directory